# Extreme points of prefix sum and prefix sum of subsets.

Tags: convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

Given an ordered set of points $P = (p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_n)$, where $p_i \in R^d$.

The prefix sum set $S$ of $P$ is defined as
$$
S = (p_1, p_1+p_2, p_1+p_2+p_3, \cdots, \sum_{i=1}^n p_i)
$$

And there exists a convex hull of $S$ denote $CH(S)$, a subset of elements of $S$ on the boundary of $CH(S)$ is referred to as extreme points $E = Boudardy(CH(S)) \cap S$.

$E := f(P)$

The interest is that given an index set $I$ of $P$ and $E$, How can I find the extreme points of it namely $f(P_I)$ as efficient as possible?

E.g. $d=2, n=5$.

$$
P = ([0, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 7]) \\
S = ([0,  1],
       [ 2,  2],
       [ 2,  4],
       [ 4,  7],
       [ 6, 14]) \\
E = (
       [ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  2],
       [ 4,  7], [ 6, 14])\\
$$
Given $I= (0, 1, 2)$

Then $P_I = ([0, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 2],)$, $S_I=([0,  1],
       [ 2,  2],
       [ 2,  4],)$ and $E_I$ was simply be the same as $S_I$ .

Another example, in a $d=2$ case, if the ordering of $P$ is the same as the ordering of $tan^{-1}(p_i[1], p_i[0])$, then $E_I$ is always going to be the same as S_I.

Comment: Interesting question! I'm not sure if this is terribly efficient, but you could probably build this iteratively. At each stage, $i\in I$, it appears that $\sum_{1\leq i\leq i+1}p_i\in E$ if $p_{i+1}\not\in\textrm{span}\{p_j\, |\, 1\leq j\leq i\text{ and }j\in E\}$. Unfortunately I don't think this condition is also necessary :( but you could use something like Gram-Schmidt for checking the condition

Comment: so the idea is that $E$ is already known, but we want to get $E_I$, since $I$ can change depending on different settings.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Quickhull or Graham Scan algorithms yield lower bounds on computational efficiency. So I guess the question is whether or not we can use the problem structure to do any better.

Comment: yeah, thanks for looking into it! I was thinking of cutting the $S$ iteratively based on elements $A \in I$ into two half. and then translate one side to the other, treating $p_A$ is missing. merging two convex hull can be obtained in linear time.

Comment: I am removing the `finite-geometry` tag, since this tag is for geometric spaces that only have a finite number of points and lines (such as those defined over a finite field) rather than for discrete geometric configurations such as this. I have replaced it with the `discrete-geometry` tag.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out and sorry about the misuse :) and I might have some partial answer to this question